# What is the connection between game theory and (modal) logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, game-theory, modal-logic

I'm interested in dynamic epistemic logic lately (reasoning about information and change in multi-agent systems). I also like game theory. I'm looking for some good resources about the connection between those topics.

How can one apply dynamic epistemic (or any other modal) logic to games?

I'd like to know how concepts like general knowledge, common knowledge, epistemic actions, public announcements, action moidels etc. relate to game theory topics.

Comment: You can see [Logic and Games](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-games/) with some references to modal logic, and the book : Jouko Vaananen, [Models and Games](https://books.google.it/books?id=uDDDbkfZpIEC&printsec=frontcover) (2011).